# OBD2 Reading Enhanced Parameters with Python (ex. Injector Pulsewidth)

Tags: python, serial-port, obd-ii, elm327

I'm working on a project to capture instantaneous fuel consumption and I'd like to use injector pulsewidth.
I'm using pyserial to get the parameters connected to a bluetooth OBD reader.

For example, to get speed I type:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM6',38400,timeout=1)

ser.write('01 0D \r')

speed_hex=ser.readline()

print speed_hex
```

To call any other standard OBD2 parameter, I'd just type it's 4 digit code followed by \r. This also worked for me with RPM, etc...

However I need fuel injector pulsewidth from a GMC vehicle which is code 125A, but typing '12 5A \r' doesn't give me any data. I suspect because it's part of the extended parameters and I'm not typing it correctly.

Can someone help me figure out how to get this parameter? I know it's available for my truck because I am comparing it with a windows GUI software which was able to obtain logical values for this parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try : `11 5A \r` why ? Because you try reading malfunction code. Do you have any injection problems ? @regerd20

Comment: According to this website: http://www.fastfieros.com/tech/vpw_communication_protocol.htm the code for fuel injection pulsewidth for a GMC vehicle is 125A. I don't have injection problems but rather I want to track the pulsewidth over time.

Comment: `12` is not your starting point ! My idea always starts with `01 12 5A`. Because `01` is `Request Current Powertrain Diagnostic Data `

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that out tomorrow when I get home from work.